# hide a div by clicking a non-parent div

Tags: css, html, hide, parent, show-hide

In my site there're two different div, but they have the same parent div (two child div). So, I want to do this: `div.1:hover` -> `div.2{display:none}`. How can I do it using CSS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the way your HTML is laid out it can work. The divs need to be next to each other like so:

```
<div class="first">
  First div
</div>
<div class="second">
  Second div
</div>
```

Then use this CSS:

```
div.first:hover + div.second { display: none; }
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CyT2N/

Comment: No, the two div are not consecutive and the :hover is applied to the second div.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily accomplish that with [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

```
$(document).ready(function(){$("#first").hover(function(){$("#second").hide();}, function(){$("#second").show();});});
```

**Explanation:**
this code adds a "hover" handler for the first element on document.ready, when the mouse enters we hide the second element, and when the mouse leaves, we show it again.

This way, it will work no matter where the elements are within the layout.

**See here:** http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/RenK2/

**Edit**
If you want the second div to hide when the first one is clicked, use `$("#first").click(function(){$("#second").hide();})` instead of `hover(..)`

**See here:** http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/RenK2/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way of doing it:

If you have **HTML** similar to this:

```
<div class="wrap">
    <div class="first">First div</div>
    <p>some other element...</p>
    <div class="second">Second div</div>
</div>
```

your **CSS** would be:

```css
.first:hover ~ .second {
    display: none;
}
```

Demo at: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/HQN6n/

The one limitation that `.first` and `.second` must be sibling elements within the same parent element, `.wrap` in this example.

The general sibling combinator `~` is supported for IE7+

**Reference:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors